# Shortcut for empty Handlebars in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, sublimetext3, shortcut

I use the following shortcut for `erb` tags in Sublime Text :

```
{ "keys": ["option+."], "command": "erb", "context":
  [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.ruby, text.haml, source.yaml, source.css, source.scss, source.js, source.coffee" }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please help me make a shortcut to show empty Handlebars (Ember app) so that by pressing `option + /` I can produce `{{  }}` (the space created in the middle would be where the carrot starts, to enter text).

I'm already using https://github.com/daaain/Handlebars but this package doesn't produce empty handlebars.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by using the `insert_snippet` command:

```
{
    "keys": ["option+/"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": { "contents": "{{ ${1} }}" },
    "context": [ { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.ruby, text.haml, source.yaml, source.css, source.scss, source.js, source.coffee" } ]
},
```

---

**Reference:**

[**Sublime Text > Unofficial Docs > Snippets**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I changed the shortcut keys to `option+/` just out of preference.

Comment: @JoshZandman: My bad, forgot to add `option` back in after testing lol. Just updated @ answer.